# why window.getSelection() is not working? It won't take the text

Tags: javascript, window, console.log, getselection

I'm trying to paste in the console the text from the screen that I select.

So, I've got some example text and in my js file I have:

```
let text = window.getSelection().toString()
console.log(text)
```

That's the only content of the file, as this is a test. But it won't work.
If I print a console log with an example, like `console.log('whatever')` it does print "whatever" into the console.

Why is not working?

Comment: At the time your script runs, there's no selection on the page.

Comment: I would like someone to tell me why the downvote, so I can improve the question. I don't think that I've missed anything or it's badly formulated. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't vote on the question, but "_it won't work_" is not a problem description. You should tell what you want your code to do, and what it does instead, in the text, never hide the explanation in the title only.

Comment: I see. You're right. Thanks for the clarification! :)

Answer (score 2):

If that is the only content of the file, then it is going to run as soon as the `<script>` element is parsed.

At that point, the user almost certainly won't have selected anything, so the selection is empty and you'll get an empty string.

Put the code in a function and use an event handler so it doesn't run until there is a selection.

```js
function handler(event) {
  let text = window.getSelection().toString()
  console.log(text)
}

addEventListener("mouseup", handler);
```

```html
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
```

Comment: Very clear explanation about why it wouldn't work. Thank you!